# Element found using Selenium expected conditions but doesn't appear in the page source

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

The page I'm trying to scrape is http://zipatlas.com/us/oh/zip-code-comparison/population-below-poverty-level.1.htm

It loads some content through javascript, so I'm trying to use the expected_conditions module in selenium to detect it. What happens is that I apparently detect the element I'm looking for, but when I print the page source, it doesn't contain that element. There's a link labeled "TEST LINK" at the bottom of the page, so I figured if that has loaded, the rest of the page pretty much has also.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


curr_url = r"http://zipatlas.com/us/oh/zip-code-comparison/population-below-poverty-level.1.htm"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(curr_url)
try: 
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'TEST LINK')))
except TimeoutException:
    print("took too long to load")
print("element detected")
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text('TEST LINK')
html = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
print(html)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.close()
```

I do successfully print out the detected element as `<a href="">TEST LINK</a>`

However, in the page_source that is printed out, I cannot find this. The page source is located [here](https://pastebin.com/aKUpBUJw). I also tried using other expected_conditions like `element_to_be_clickable`

So my question is why is the located element not appearing in the page source? Also, is there any other way to detect that the whole page has loaded? Using expected_conditions is really the only potential solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Before you exract the `outerHTML` of the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336).

You can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('http://zipatlas.com/us/oh/zip-code-comparison/population-below-poverty-level.1.htm')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'TEST LINK'))).get_attribute("outerHTML"))
  print("==========")
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
    <a href="">TEST LINK</a>
    ==========
    <html><head><title>
        Zip Codes with the Highest Percentage of Population Below Poverty Level in Ohio | Zip Atlas
    </title>



    <meta name="robots" content="all,index,follow"><meta name="rating" content="general"><meta name="author" content="ZipAtlas.com Development Team"><meta name="language" content="en-us"><meta name="copyright" content="Copyright 2011 ZipAtlas.com"><meta name="revisit-after" content="7 Days"><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"><meta http-equiv="Distribution" content="Global"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><meta name="google-site-verification" content="3cRw56ihbmZI3sma1cdmLLpkwcJEE_L1tUFYhaet2xQ">

        <style type="text/css">
            body, td, div, span, p { color: #333333; font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }
            select { color: #333333; font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; border: solid 1px #5A81A6; }
            a { text-decoration: none; color: #0000D0; }
            a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #0000D0; }
            h1 { margin:0px 0px 10px 0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; color: #3d7795;}
            h2 { margin:35px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; color: #3d7795;}
            h3 { margin:35px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; color: #3d7795;}

            span.link { cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #0000D0; }
            span.link:hover { cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline; color: #0000D0; }

            td.report_header { border: solid 1px #5A81A6; background-color: #5A81A6; color: #ffffff; }
            td.report_data { border: solid 1px #5A81A6; padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px; font-size: 12px; }
        </style>
    <link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.co.in/adsid/integrator.js?domain=zipatlas.com" as="script"><script src="https://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/cookie.js?domain=zipatlas.com&amp;callback=_gfp_s_&amp;client=ca-pub-7710991166856237"></script><script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20200624/r20190131/show_ads_impl_fy2019.js" id="google_shimpl"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.co.in/adsid/integrator.js?domain=zipatlas.com"></script><link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=zipatlas.com" as="script"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=zipatlas.com"></script><script src="https://www.google.com/cse/static/element/57975621473fd078/cse_element__en.js?usqp=CAI%3D" type="text/javascript"></script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.google.com/cse/static/element/57975621473fd078/default_v2+en.css"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.google.com/cse/static/style/look/v4/default.css"></head>
    <body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background: url('/images/bg.gif');">

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td style="background: url('/images/shadow-left.gif') top right repeat-y;" valign="top">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;height:200px; background: url('/images/bg-top-left.gif') top right no-repeat;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
                <td style="width:930px;background:url('/images/bg-top.gif') top left repeat-x;" valign="top">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/"><img border="0" src="/images/logo.gif" alt="ZipAtlas Home"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" valign="bottom" style="color: #c0c0c0; padding-bottom: 3px; font-size: 13px;">
                                <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="/downloads/">Database Download</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; background-color:#ffffff;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; height:550px;" valign="top">


        <!--<form action="/" method="get">//-->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border-bottom: solid 1px #f0f5f9;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><h1>Zip Codes with the Highest Percentage of Population Below Poverty Level in Ohio</h1></td>
                <td align="right" valign="top">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td><a href="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent('http://zipatlas.com/us/oh/zip-code-comparison/population-below-poverty-level.1.htm'), 'pf','height=400,width=550').focus())"><img border="0" src="/images/social/facebook-s.gif"></a></td>
                            <td style="padding-left:1px;"><a href="javascript:void(window.open('http://twitter.com/home?status='+encodeURIComponent('http://zipatlas.com/us/oh/zip-code-comparison/population-below-poverty-level.1.htm')).focus())"><img border="0" src="/images/social/twitter-s.gif"></a></td>
                            <td style="padding-left:1px;"><a href="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.myspace.com/Modules/PostTo/Pages/?u='+encodeURIComponent('http://zipatlas.com/us/oh/zip-code-comparison/population-below-poverty-level.1.htm'),'pm','height=450,width=440').focus())"><img border="0" src="/images/social/myspace-s.gif"></a></td>

                            <!--<td style="padding-left:15px;"><input type="text" name="q" style="width:175px;" value="" /></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>//-->
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

        <!--</form>//-->

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border-bottom: solid 1px #f0f5f9;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td style="padding:15px 0px 10px 0px;" align="center">
            <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=013012024412622983838:nucmfhluwdu"></script><script>
                (function () {
                var cx = '013012024412622983838:nucmfhluwdu';
                var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                gcse.async = true;
                gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                })();
            </script>
            <gcse:search></gcse:search>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border-bottom: solid 1px #f0f5f9">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td style="padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;" align="center">
                    <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                    <!-- ZipAtlas - 3 Across (Mixed) -->
                    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7710991166856237" data-ad-slot="2630863889" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_0_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:250px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:300px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_0_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:250px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:300px;background-color:transparent;"></ins></ins></ins>
                    <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                    </script>
                </td>
                <td style="padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;" align="center">
                    <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                    <!-- ZipAtlas - 3 Across (Mixed) -->
                    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7710991166856237" data-ad-slot="2630863889" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_1_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:250px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:300px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_1_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:250px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:300px;background-color:transparent;"></ins></ins></ins>
                    <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                    </script>
                </td>
                <td style="padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;" align="center">
                    <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                    <!-- ZipAtlas - 3 Across (Mixed) -->
                    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7710991166856237" data-ad-slot="2630863889" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_2_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:250px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:300px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_2_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:250px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:300px;background-color:transparent;"></ins></ins></ins>
                    <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_final_content" style="padding-top:10px;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="padding-left:3px;">Ohio Report:</td>
                        <td style="padding-left:5px;">
                            <div style="border: solid 1px #5A81A6; cursor:pointer; padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px; background-color: #FFFFD0; color: #5A81A6;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#5A81A6';this.style.color='#ffffff';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFD0';this.style.color='#5A81A6';" onclick="onContextMenu(event);" title="Click to select a different Ohio report">
                                Percentage of Population Below Poverty Level
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

                <td style="background: url('/images/shadow-right.gif') top left repeat-y;" valign="top">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;height:200px; background: url('/images/bg-top-right.gif') top left no-repeat;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><img src="/images/shadow-ll.gif"></td>
                <td style="background: url('/images/edge-bottom.gif') top left repeat-x;">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
                        <tbody><tr><td><img src="/images/shadow-lr.gif"></td>
                        <td align="right"><img src="/images/shadow-rl.gif"></td>
                    </tr></tbody></table>
                </td>
                <td><img src="/images/shadow-rr.gif"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

        <center>
            <div style="color:#c0c0c0; padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;">
                <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="/">Zip Atlas Home</a> |
                <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="/downloads/">Downloads</a> |
            <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="https://ecovinyl.ca">ecoVinyl</a> |
                <a href="">TEST LINK</a>

                <br><br>

                <font color="#ffffff">© 2020 ZipAtlas.Com</font>
            </div>
        </center>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Set(el_name, c)
            {
                var el = document.getElementById(el_name);
                if (el)
                {
                    el.innerHTML = c;
                }
            }
            function Show(el_name)
            {
                var el = document.getElementById(el_name);
                if (el)
                {
                    el.style.display = '';
                }
            }
            function Hide(el_name)
            {
                var el = document.getElementById(el_name);
                if (el)
                {
                    el.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        </script>

    <!-- expo-MAX Code Start //-->
    <!-- Paste this code into every page that you would like to track //-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(unescape('%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="'+document.location.protocol+'//expo-max.com/adserver/js/"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
    </script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://expo-max.com/adserver/js/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        expomax_trace('WunfWYG%2bFajQ%2f9F4kqiaXg%3d%3d','cb959e484ba8457ca327aeefce4cb2b4');
    </script><div id="g5ef264d7a54140f7b03eff0ea8cfe256" style="display:none;"><iframe style="display:none;" src="https://expo-max.com/adserver/track/?e=WunfWYG%2bFajQ%2f9F4kqiaXg%3d%3d&amp;a=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F83.0.4103.116%20Safari%2F537.36&amp;l=http%3A%2F%2Fzipatlas.com%2Fus%2Foh%2Fzip-code-comparison%2Fpopulation-below-poverty-level.1.htm&amp;r=&amp;w=1366&amp;h=768&amp;p=http:"></iframe></div>
    <!-- expo-MAX Code End //-->



    <ins class="adsbygoogle adsbygoogle-noablate" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" style="display: none !important;"><ins id="aswift_3_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:0px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_3_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:0px;background-color:transparent;"></ins></ins></ins></body><iframe id="google_esf" name="google_esf" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/html/r20200624/r20190131/zrt_lookup.html#" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7710991166856237" style="display: none;"></iframe></html>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I don't think it has anything to do with that, since I do call WebDriverWait in the try/except block. I ended up writing the driver.page_source to a file, and the full html appeared. Maybe it has something to do with the console output in visual studio code.

Comment: @fooiey The [expected_conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) of `presence_of_element_located()` and `element_to_be_clickable()` have a difference in their implementation.